# eth0 not getting disabled after setting up br0 interface

Tags: debian, networking, bridge

On debian squeeze, I setup a bridge based on eth0. My `/etc/network/interfaces` is

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
#allow-hotplug eth1
#auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
iface eth0 inet6 manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
    bridge_ports    eth0
    bridge_stp      off
#    bridge_maxwait  0
    bridge_fd       9
bridge_hello 2
bridge_maxage 12
```

Despite setting eth0 to manual, it get's an ip address via DHCP. Setting `ifconfig eth0 down` explicitly, disables the interface for a few seconds before it comes back up again.

How can I disable eth0 and use br0 has my only network interface?

Comment: I'm not sure about this (that's why it's a comment), but have you tried restarting the network manager so it will accept eth0 as manual?

Comment: You try to comment all lines for eth0 (except the bridge_ports one of course) and restart networking.

Comment: Are you running NetworkManager or Wicd? Without them the interface shouldn't come up automatically. Check the system logs (`/var/log/*`, look for files modified around the time the network came up) for clues.

Comment: Wicd was running. Can you write it as an answer, so I can close this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gilles appears to have [answered](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56766/eth0-not-getting-disabled-after-setting-up-br0-interface#comment78250_56766) this one in the comments, with:

> Are you running NetworkManager or Wicd?

as followed up by the OP:

> Wicd was running.